# Smooth interpolation of object orientation to track the camera

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I have a SCNNode that represents an item held by the player in a first-person game (using ARKit).

I made the node a child of the camera so that it always floats a short distance in front of the viewer. But this simple setup makes the item very static, just glued to the screen.

More realistically, if I were holding an object in front of me, and then turned to face a different direction, my hand movement would lag a little bit behind my head. And if I tilted my head up or down, my perspective of the object would change slightly as well.

How could I emulate this in SceneKit?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861010/chase-camera-in-scenekit) has some ideas for a camera that chases a node with a delay, and that might work in reverse. For tilting, maybe I'd have to factor in the accelerometer, but constrain it so that you can't rotate the object too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the item a child of the camera, I made the item a child of a new invisible node called `arms`. The `arms` node is not a child of camera, but I used an `SCNTransformConstraint` to constrain its transformation, like this:

```
    // ~~ Not the final code ~~ Do not use ~~
    // Set up the viewer's "arms" to follow the camera using a dampened constraint
    arms = SCNNode()
    let armconstraint = SCNTransformConstraint.init(inWorldSpace: false) {
        (node: SCNNode, _) -> SCNMatrix4 in

        // Bind the arm's transformation to the camera's
        return self.sceneView.pointOfView!.convertTransform(SCNMatrix4Identity, to: node)
    }
    armconstraint.influenceFactor = 0.5
    arms!.constraints = [ armconstraint ]
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(arms!)
```

The idea of using a low `influenceFactor` so that the `arms` are not rigidly held in front of the camera, but follow it with a small delay.

This works so-so; it can be noticeably jerky. So I tried splitting it up into two separate constraints: a `SCNDistanceConstraint` that maintains a distance of 0 between the camera and `arms`, and a `SCNTransformConstraint` which syncs the `arms` orientation but not its position.

What I found is that while the *distance* constraint was flawless, using a fractional `influenceFactor` on the orientation caused the `arms` to go berserk, spinning wildly across the screen! If it was `1.0` then the `arms` node follows the camera rigidly but without glitching.

It turns out, in the documentation of `SCNConstraint.influenceFactor`, it says:

> This property has no effect on `SCNTransformConstraint` objects.

Huh, I wonder why—an node's `transform`, `position`, and `orientation` are animatable so it seems they could be interpolated smoothly no problems.

It turns out there is a technique called [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) which is a way to interpolate between quaternions. So rather than use `influenceFactor`, each time my `SCNTransformConstraint` is invoked I can interpolate between the current position of `arms` and the position of the camera. This is acceptably smooth.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Note that in iOS 11, there are many more `SCNConstraint` types, so you can get a lot more done by chaining replicator, acceleration, and distance constraints instead of writing transform-matrix-munging blocks yourself. (I updated the question you linked to with more details / examples.)

Comment: My assumption is that the jerkiness is either due to rounding errors, or because ARKit is constantly re-calculating the position of the camera within the scene based on new data.

I tried using a `SCNDistanceConstraint` to hold the `arms` object at a distance of 0 from the camera. This works well but it does not keep the rotation in sync also.

Comment: Whew. This was a more involved effect than I was expecting, but I updated my answer with the real solution.